# Try to use Insert On Duplicate Key update command in MYSQL, but one table doesn't have PK

Tags: mysql

I have two table :

MST table:

```
ID     (PK INT)
Content (Varchar255)
NAME    (Varchar255)
```

STG table:

```
ID     (INT)                 * not Primary Key
Content (Varchar255)
NAME    (Varchar255)
```

Then how can I insert data from STG to MST table, if there is duplicate in ID I will update the rest of columns, or insert new rows.

Comment: The duplicate key test ONLY applies to the target table.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter does the source has PK/UNIQUE. Each separate insert performs separate and independent check on target table only.

But you must have some definite source data ordering - the result depends on it.

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=338fe3e2850c512cd45312c14b3b7b9d) - different ordering causes different result.

Answer (score 0):

I have a method where in you can insert data into MTG but duplicate `ID` won't be inserted into `MTG`

First, we create a table

```
create table MTG like STG;
```

This will create a table like STG, but won't insert the records in it.
Remember only the columns, its attributes and constraints are copied by using `like` clause.

```
desc MTG;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID      | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| content | varchar(225) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Name    | varchar(225) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Then we modify `MTG` column `ID` to make it `primary key`

```
alter table MTG modify id int primary key;
```

I have inserted some fake data in STG which is like:

```
select * from STG;
+------+---------+---------+
| ID   | content | Name    |
+------+---------+---------+
|    1 | FUN     | Swap    |
|    1 | Vines   | Swapnil |
|    2 | dint    | Raj     |
+------+---------+---------+
```

As soon as we fire  below Query

```
insert ignore into MTG select * from STG;
```

It will ignore duplicate records.
as you can see

```
+----+---------+------+
| id | content | Name |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | FUN     | Swap |
|  2 | dint    | Raj  |
+----+---------+------+
```